# Debayering bayer encoded Raw Images

Tags: image

I have an image which I need to write a debayer for, but I can't figure out how the data is packed.
The information I have about the image:

```
original bpp: 64;
PNG bpp: 8;
columns: 242;
rows: 3944;
data size: 7635584 bytes.
```

PNG https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fr8Tg3OvhavsgYTwjJnUG3vz-kZcRpi9/view?usp=sharing

SRC data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_3tfeln76faqgewAknYKJKCbDq8UjEz/view?usp=sharing
I was told that it should be BGGR, but it doesn't look like any ordinary Bayer BGGR image to me. Also I got the image with a txt file which contains this text:

```
Camera resolution: 1280x944
Camera type: LVDS
```

Could the image be compressed somehow?

I'm completely lost here, I would appreciate any help.

[Bayer pattern of the image in 8bpp representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl6S7.jpg)

Comment: Something is wrong with the way you shared the file. All I can see is `test.png` (I can't see the 7635584 bytes file). The data is probably not compressed because `3944*242*8` = `7635584`.

Comment: @Rotem, I attached the source binary file and update the PNG. Also I got some more information about the image. It should be 1 fisheye image, there should be a fisheye circle visible. Also I can see horizontal and vertical patterns now on bright parts of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are 4 images, and the pixels are stored in some kind of "packed 12" format.

Please note that "reverse engineering" the format is challenging, and the solution probably has few mistakes.

---

The 4 images are stored in steps of 4 rows:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddd
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddd
...
```

`aaa...` marks the first image.
`bbb...` marks the second image.
`ccc...` marks the third image.
`ddd...` marks the fourth image.

There are about 168 rows at the top that we have to ignore.

---

Getting 1280 pixels out of 1936 bytes in each row:

Each row has 16 bytes we have to ignore.
Out of 1936 bytes, only 1920 bytes are relevant (assume we have to remove 8 bytes from each side).

The 1920 bytes represents 1280 pixels.
Every 2 pixels are stored in 3 bytes (every pixel is 12 bits).

The two 12 bits elements in 3 bytes are packed as follows:

```
8 MSB bits  8 MSB bits   4 LSB and 4 LSB bits 
########    ########     #### ####
```

It's hard to tell how the LSB bits are divided between the two pixels (the LSB it mainly "noise").

---

After unpacking the pixels, and extracting one image out of the 4, the format looks like GRBG Bayer pattern (by changing the size of the margins we may get BGGR).

---

MATLAB code sample for extracting one image:

```matlab
f = fopen('test.img', 'r'); % Open file (as binary file) for reading
T = fread(f, [1936, 168], 'uint8')'; % Read the first 168
I = fread(f, [1936, 944*4], 'uint8')'; % Read 944*4 rows
fclose(f);

% Convert from packed 12 to uint16 (also skip rows in steps of 4, and ignore 8 bytes from each side):
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
A = uint16(I(1:4:end, 8+1:3:end-8)); % MSB of even pixels (convert to uint16)
B = uint16(I(1:4:end, 8+2:3:end-8)); % MSB of odd pixels (convert to uint16)
C = uint16(I(1:4:end, 8+3:3:end-8)); % 4 bits are LSB of even pixels and 4 bits are LSB of odd pixels

I1 = A*16 + bitshift(C, -4); % Add the 4 LSB bits to the even pixels (may be a wrong)
I2 = B*16 + bitand(C, 15); % Add the other 4 LSB bits to the even pixels (may be a wrong)

I = zeros(size(I1, 1), size(I1, 2)*2, 'uint16'); % Allocate 1280x944 uint16 elements.
I(:, 1:2:end) = I1; % Copy even pixels
I(:, 2:2:end) = I2; % Copy odd pixels
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

J = demosaic(I*16, 'grbg'); % Apply demosaic (multiply by 16, because MATLAB assume 12 bits are in the upper bits).
figure;imshow(lin2rgb(J));impixelinfo % Show the output image (lin2rgb applies gamma correction).
```

---

Result (converted to 8 bit):
[image]